# T4 output filename

Tags: t4, t4-toolbox

How can i use generated file's name in template?
I'd like to something like this:

```
// This file: <#= OutputFileName #> was autogenerated
```

How can i do that in T4 or in T4Toolbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seemed like something that should be as simple as reading a property but after reflecting over the Host variable and disassembling the text generator code I think the simplest way of doing this is:

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="true"  #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO"                #>

// <#=Path.ChangeExtension (Host.TemplateFile, "cs")#>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what i meant. I don't want to specify extension manually. I want everything to be automatic. Event extension should be taken from template's variable. When i'm setting <#@ output extension="cs"#> where is it? Is there any access to this field

Comment: <#@ output extension="cs"#> calls Host.SetFileExtension ("cs"). As far as I can tell there's no public methods/properties to get the FileExtension. I tried using reflection to retrieve it (just to try) but it's complicated by the fact that it seems the Host runs in another AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

It better to define it as a directive

for example for a xaml file

```
<#@ output extension="xaml" #>
```

or for txt

```
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
```

Comment: OP was asking about how to get the output file name, so your response is OT.